# BigQuery extremely slow for small table queries with many WHERE IN parameters

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to understand why a query such as the one below on an 8mb table in BigQuery takes 10-15 seconds.

If I remove most of the WHERE IN parameters it performs as expected.

When comparing performance locally vs BigQuery with all the WHERE IN parameters it's about 20 times faster on my old netbook than it is on BigQuery.

```
SELECT  id  
FROM  `example.example.emails` 
WHERE id IN (104281,100567,100701,100941,101087,101157,101337,101391,101513,101831,101967,101973,102111,102403,102613,102653,102671,102843,103597,103613,103623,103729,104145,104163,104315,104325,104537,105165,105179,105257,105275,105291,105351,105363,105401,105797,105811,105893,106007,106315,106329,106363,106743,106829,107213,107371,107499,107501,107561,107677,107759,107873,107899,108029,108061,108093,108153,108537,108561,108599,108839,108861,108863,108895,108907,109011,109113,109227,109845,109931,110061,110221,110227,110267,110325,110471,110521,110553,110685,110977,110989,111179,111249,111291,111733,112015,112107,112139,112141,112431,112461,112641,112835,112971,113101,113123,113227,113281,113449,113549,113609,113661,113685,113905,113961,114015,114119,114427,114459,114609,114713,114839,114973,115187,115265,115453,115491,115497,115911,115915,116099,116497,116553,116825,116869,117005,117059,117089,117105,117235,117423,117597,117787,117929,118147,118297,118535,118573,118643,118841,118987,119147,119195,119273,119335,119389,119469,119555,119997,120369,120761,120875,120977,121029,121063,121107,121127,121155,121159,121187,121251,121265,121317,121337,121339,121363,121371,121427,121457,121467,121637,121683,121701,121827,121915,121949,122119,122441,122619,122663,122669,122737,122867,122919,122999,123121,123139,123257,123655,123741,123889,124123,124145,124221,124309,124833,124837,124909,124925,124991,125015,125019,125073,125391,125467,125725,125743,125827,125851,125895,126033,126069,126107,126593,126687,127005,127017,127059,127235,127473,128137,128201,128267,128323,128417,128539,128741,128751,129049,129245,129325,129691,129877,130329,130337,130769,131231,131317,131389,131413,131505,131591,131725,131961,131971,132081,132155,132277,132297,132299,132359,132361,132363,132365,132367,132375,132599,132613,132625,132635,132721,132747,132925,132947,133401,133493,133525,134283,134787,134801,134803,134807,134837,134845,135161,135195,135199,135271,135283,135285,135303,135311,135347,135361,135707,135869,135889,135913,136155,136205,136523,136621,136751,136757,136845,136875,136877,137127,137143,137155,137509,137623,137637,137693,137719,137739,138013,138279,138343,138553,138731,138761,138847,138929,139413,139489,139507,139995,140031,140105,140725,140813,140867,140883,140917,140993,141109,141135,141197,141265,141721,141729,141763,141849,141907,141939,141971,141973,142033,14244,142779,142797,14290,142931,143029,143153,143403,143639,143707,143711,143713,143737,143739,143745,143773,143779,143783,143791,143793,143807,143827,143829,143833,143849,143851,143853,143855,143863,143883,143887,143889,143967,144219,144311,14445,144569,144745,145357,145439,145545,145679,145681,145757,146133,146391,146407,146475,146605,146751,146989,147089,147161,147381,147543,147679,147693,14771,14783,147889,147969,14817,148533,14861,148761,148781,149101,149157,149231,149331,149333,14936,149517,149525,149725,149745,149857,15001,150079,150139,150167,150259,150345,150697,15084,151037,151115,151341,151399,15140,151423,151431,151503,151513,151543,151603,151607,151617,152079,15228,152345,152413,152529,152635,152805,152889,152901,152933,152955,152965,152977,153003,153099,153165,153189,153277,153533,153749,15401,154307,15436,154419,154667,154687,15471,154863,154883,15506,155115,155215,155321,155467,155491,155529,155549,155697,155923,155971,156279,156311,156315,156319,156389,156525,156535,156539,156617,156643,156685,156689,156695,156715,15689,157009,157551,157607,157765,157839,157945,157997,158015,15805,158059,15825,15827,158393,158413,15850,158537,158641,158669,15874,158889,159141,159455,159565,159637,15965,159795,159821,159843,160063,160095,160105,160355,160443,160535,160537,160549,16083,16109,161173,161201,161371,161563,162009,162123,162175,162281,162513,162661,162675,162765,162801,16304,163043,16345,164021,16444,164659,164831,164967,165541,165551,165563,165631,165639,165755,165883,165959,165985,165991,166009,166027,166029,166407,166591,166727,166769,166809,166847,166973,167125,167459,167551,167573,167655,16791,16797,168371,16856,168981,169729,169743,169865,16992,170079,170149,17050,170559,170587,170847,17098,171047,171199,17122,171253,171281,171379,171543,17157,171593,171713,171837,172005,172015,172041,17223,17240,17248,172503,172709,172953,173423,173437,173497,173527,173555,173655,173693,173711,173743,173765,173805,173823,173825,173897,174007,174225,174261,174337,174447,174599,17472,174805,174853,174899,175263,175339,17540,175489,17550,175607,175655,175813,175853,176213,176247,176355,176423,176429,176561,176683,176851,176857,17688,177021,17722,17726,177431,177543,177797,178135,178235,178409,178677,178725,178855,178907,178981,179053,17906,179507,179557,179625,179857,180249,180269,181049,181067,181097,181305,181429,181499,181565,181701,181771,182017,182169,182321,182689,18276,183061,183261,183589,183895,183897,183947,184091,184171,184191,184627,184635,184653,184659,184797,184907,185291,185905,185981,186513,186519,186541,186567,186665,18676,186799,187243,187247,18752,187585,187591,187617,187941,187949,188123,188281,18831,188581,188587,188607,188743,188965,189221,189393,189513,18969,189743,189787,189869,190249,190539,190557,190769,190777,190801,190903,190949,191359,191417,191447,191561,191819,191823,191873,191879,191975,192001,192111,19231,192497,192617,192737,192851,192909,19297,19300,193069,193095,193155,19328,193459,193645,193971,193979,194027,194053,194657,194837,195225,19527,195271,195321,195503,196013,196107,196673,196843,196863,196865,196959,197043,197261,197489,197569,197765,198085,198135,198233,198399,198513,19887,20163,20214,20222,20250,20346,20396,20468,20632,20664,20679,20736,20764,20766,20780,20789,20809,20813,20847,20861,20899,20906,20914,20951,21071,21107,21132,21171,21176,21348,21428,21475,21631,21937,22043,22107,22241,22297,22729,22750,22755,22787,22814,22865,23034,23173,23206,23260,23276,23311,23350,23355,23395,23420,23445,23545,23726,23839,23899,23907,24402,24619,24643,24692,24712,24781,24786,25098,25112,25236,25266,25393,25428,25439,25502,25512,25553,25734,25735,25753,25789,25800,25814,25960,26007,26068,26083,26084,26085,26152,26164,26212,26231,26260,26283,26376,26411,26617,26652,26664,26741,26758,26773,26790,26885,26949,26976,27100,27193,27287,27325,27400,27467,27528,27587,27714,27814,27840,27911,28020,28102,28239,28246,28262,28279,28306,28316,28364,28387,28447,28533,28555,28602,28709,28824,28870,29031,29076,29095,29119,29159,29161,29331,29340,29420,29464,29532,29643,29781,29898,30017,30020,30033,30084,30123,30124,30140,30150,30158,30176,30216,30249,30276,30305,30343,30350,30397,30403,30581,30595,30731,30787,30793,30842,31063,31153,31182,31186,31193,31247,31390,31437,31460,31548,31559,31683,31703,31722,31736,31837,31918,31977,32006,32021,32142,32247,32262,32283,32297,32442,32532,32591,32607,32662,32687,32724,32764,32821,32904,32905,32921,32928,32993,33172,33185,33240,33261,33299,33303,33334,33336,33341,33452,33490,33539,33584,33627,33635,33698,33724,33740,33945,33964,33971,33982,34082,34211,34242,34244,34390,34397,34402,34438,34471,34654,34684,34759,34886,34920,34978,34981,35015,35068,35165,35175,35276,35390,35438,35486,35628,35668,35777,35819,35863,36008,36035,36062,36070,36130,36157,36170,36190,36336,36413,36420,36450,36469,36475,36575,36608,36612,36651,36825,36826,36875,37008,37081,37106,37124,37213,37326,37402,37688,37898,38020,38079,38123,38170,38198,38241,38646,38883,38990,39030,39050,39126,39141,39165,39300,39316,39355,39387,39431,39447,39480,39481,39505,39559,39642,39717,39776,39783,39787,39896,40006,40041,40055,40138,40217,40243,40256,40286,40299,40313,40344,40391,40419,40452,40547,40560,40564,40670,40699,40726,40756,40825,40897,40948,41024,41078,41091,41131,41276,41283,41316,41336,41471,41476,41506,41677,41698,41771,41835,41880,42104,42248,42251,42292,42316,42324,42430,42439,42443,42444,42460,42517,42530,42607,42668,42688,42750,42755,42792,42846,42951,42987,43077,43212,43313,43327,43471,43500,43550,43577,43582,43599,43654,43734,43774,43788,43810,43857,43859,43914,44211,44408,44503,44644,44823,44839,44852,44912,44939,44943,44981,44997,45089,45137,45186,45189,45455,45586,45670,45785,45864,45903,46001,46032,46139,46147,46294,46392,46508,46518,46545,46548,46575,46837,46840,46842,46860,46890,46907,46935,47000,47066,47180,47211,47216,47217,47251,47281,47660,47698,47879,48166,48207,48381,48415,48466,48541,48567,48674,48765,48779,48799,48824,48893,49018,49052,49115,49326,49331,49342,49345,49439,49468,49729,49743,49750,49789,49977,50038,50080,50148,50313,50315,50325,50374,50388,50410,50414,50430,50573,50696,50743,50769,50795,50803,50858,50891,50895,50964,50990,51010,51082,51114,51132,51152,51291,51324,51366,51575,51875,51955,51961,52028,52071,52184,52236,52239,52277,52502,52666,52710,52772,52783,52855,52933,52959,52974,53021,53053,53098,53182,53259,53320,53324,53416,53475,53660,53662,53676,53706,53787,53921,53995,54063,54077,54190,54256,54263,54374,54377,54408,54554,54563,54570,54586,54590,54607,54983,55014,55079,55101,55152,55248,55264,55275,55282,55290,55351,55453,55510,55635,55649,55760,55773,55788,55968,56208,56242,56358,56447,56459,56529,56536,56537,56619,56704,56736,56942,56991,57009,57064,57150,57152,57153,57216,57241,57372,57435,57535,57593,57792,57816,57854,57903,57928,57934,57945,58209,58214,58272,58273,58307,58320,58325,58461,58467,58512,58522,58593,58604,58683,58758,58938,58969,59074,59202,59220,59271,59278,59286,59297,59324,59341,59377,59378,59406,59453,59458,59468,59505,59515,59519,59527,59553,59568,59594,59627,59651,59919,59920,59979,60013,60038,60163,60360,60390,60414,60489,60506,60606,60708,60718,60720,60805,60885,60934,60935,60941,60981,61030,61042,61206,61303,61344,61516,61537,61709,61725,61743,62167,62293,62343,62514,62630,62634,62708,62763,62771,63053,63076,63183,63411,63483,63493,63542,63583,63631,63695,63700,63723,63741,63762,63772,63846,63872,63893,63911,63947,63963,63971,63986,64076,64082,64106,64126,64211,64232,64249,64461,64473,64482,64483,64583,64594,64664,64733,64760,64785,64866,64873,64974,65009,65010,65043,65089,65093,65217,65259,65342,65397,65489,65539,65682,66261,66265,66272,66436,66634,66751,67165,67252,67363,67472,67487,67626,67856,67901,67914,68085,68117,68402,68404,68623,68674,68757,68770,68794,68834,68845,68867,68903,69107,69175,69209,69247,69315,69486,69652,69755,69801,69809,70027,70239,70299,70361,70782,70834,70851,70884,70952,71112,71139,71154,71411,71557,71615,71711,71718,71806,71871,71964,71986,72066,72083,72603,72709,72999,73063,73287,73293,73406,73606,73726,73728,73734,73766,73778,73899,74326,74421,74727,74835,74859,75047,75127,75207,75583,76031,76061,76069,76217,76259,76333,76423,76553,76679,76687,76699,76723,76847,76877,76925,76951,77192,77299,77307,77411,77681,77819,77847,77933,77981,78005,78099,78431,78745,78955,79009,79093,79121,79159,79165,79239,79403,79787,79909,80001,80037,80069,80279,80449,80521,80717,80849,80941,80997,81006,81125,81265,81267,81355,81409,81560,81609,81717,81723,81935,81953,82019,82331,82461,82487,82631,82655,82839,82969,83001,83061,83137,83331,83413,83437,83603,83665,83929,83937,83941,83947,83949,83953,83987,84031,84093,84127,84141,84171,84185,84189,84191,84201,84309,84331,84343,84361,84383,84435,84439,84489,84501,84523,84535,84573,84613,84665,84779,84833,84932,84991,85015,85347,85367,85445,85495,85559,85571,85797,85807,85973,86157,86203,86223,86275,86447,86523,86615,86897,86915,87039,87103,87281,87475,87795,87873,89075,89197,89205,89241,89251,89261,89695,89721,89741,89783,90325,90425,90845,90861,90915,90995,91009,91091,91131,91165,91169,91197,91201,91233,91307,91429,91477,91479,91491,91511,91567,91649,91999,92339,92457,92617,92759,92765,92907,93035,93417,93525,93691,93763,93805,93917,94043,94051,94193,94303,94847,95041,95433,95475,95545,95557,95645,95749,95885,96153,96211,96417,96479,96567,96639,96651,96673,96773,96791,96853,96921,96943,97053,97073,97495,97597,97625,97681,97697,97727,98241,98377,98519,98817,98895,98937,98991,98993,99007,99067,99555,99569,99643,99647,99657,99781,137953)
```

I don't believe my table to be anything unusual.

[image]

Just in case anyone asks why I'm running BigQuery on an 8mb table...this 8mb table is part of a data set that contains much larger tables 1TB+ and is far easier for me/my application if it's all in one place.

**EDIT**

Here is the execution data for a similar query with 3140 INs on a 14mb table. This takes 50 seconds.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried writing the selections to a temporary table then JOINing to that, rather than using IN?

Comment: Yeah, while it shouldn't be as slow as OP is describing, this is a ridiculous query.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery team flagged it as a bug. The workaround is to use WHERE id IN UNNEST([1,2,3,...]) instead of WHERE id IN (1,2,3,...).